# Unspecified error using $.ajax in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a simple bit of code...

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (json) {
            alert (json);
        },
        error: function (object, text_status, error_thrown) {
            alert ('Error: '+ url +' : '+ object +' : '+ text_status +' : '+ error_thrown);
        }
    });
```

Which should work, only doesn't.  It simply displayes the error `'Error: *url* : [object Object] : error : '` which isn't exactly useful.  Going to the URL directly in my browser works fine.

Update:

The object doesn't really help either: `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

Comment: Maybe there's something **in** the Object ...

Comment: Maybe, but I am unsure as to how to get at it.

Comment: building on @Pointy's comment, try throwing in a `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))` in there or something similar.

Comment: What does Firebug say? What HTTP status code are you getting back?

Comment: Maybe `object` is a reserved keyword: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: do console.log(object); whilst using firebug or chrome developer tools (F12) and see what's within it. I think object.responseText probably has something worth seeing.

Comment: can you please send the url... so that we can know if it works or not...

Comment: could you try and change the var url to something else? I know url isn't a saved namespace but URL is.

Comment: console.error('Error: '+ url +' : ', object);

Comment: The URL is for an internal site at the moment, so it wont work (hence the redaction).

Comment: strigified object is: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: What does "url" contain? does removing the domain from it cause it to not request the correct file? `http://localhost:8080/foo.cfm` --> `/foo.cfm`

Comment: u can use console.log(json) and check where is problem and reply what he say

Comment: @rash111 you can't `console.log(json)` if you are getting into the error callback.

Comment: @KevinB Where is callback in above code

Comment: @rash111 It's right there in the above code, after the `error:` key to the ajax options object. The one that is alerting meep3d to there being an error...

Answer (score 0):

try to store the url in a different variable like `var siteurl` and use it .